# What does »fürs schwarz-schwarze Glücksprotokoll: "Die Freude unterstreiche ich."« mean?

Tags: german-to-english

The two short paragraphs below come from the article “[Merkel, Seehofer und ihr Wahlprogramm. Das Traumpaar.](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/angela-merkel-und-horst-seehofer-das-traumpaar-a-1155759.html)” in *Der Spiegel*:

> Oh, wie schön ist die Programmarbeit. Wenn man so ein Wahlprogramm aufschreibe, sagt die Kanzlerin, dann könne man noch mal "ein bisschen träumen". Weil da kann man alles hineinschreiben, was man sich wünscht.
>
> "Wann können Sie das schon mal machen?", schwärmt Angela Merkel. CSU-Chef Horst Seehofer neben ihr verkündet **fürs schwarz-schwarze Glücksprotokoll: "Die Freude unterstreiche ich."**

What does the portion of the second sentence highlighted in bold mean? I don't understand

1) why *schwarz* is used twice;

2) what's the meaning of *Glücksprotokoll*. According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=protokoll), *für das Protokoll = for the record* and *nur fürs Protokoll = just for the record*. But this still does not clarify the meaning of *Glücksprotokoll*;

3) Is Horst Seehofer saying: *I underline the joy* or *I emphasize the joy*? These are my attempts at translating *Die Freude unterstreiche ich*. Or is he saying something different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"schwarz-schwarz" relates to the two respective conservative political parties of Merkel and Seehofer, **CDU** and **CSU**, that are both traditionally associated with the color black.

*Glücksprotokoll* would be one of the famous German ad-hoc composite substantives consisting of "Glück" and "Protokoll", thus something along the line of *records of common happiness*

And yes, *unterstreichen* literally means "to underline" which doesn't work so well in speech and thus can be used to figuratively mean *emphasise*

So the sentence would roughly translate to

> Seehofer, standing next to her announces, just for the records of common black-black happiness: "I must emphasise the pleasure".

Comment: Just to complete: CSU stands for _Christlich Soziale Union_ and you can elect them only in Bavaria. CDU stands for _Christlich Demokratische Union_ and you can elect them in Germany, except Bavaria. The two parties call themself "Partner". And don't be confused, union has nothing to do with labor union. The parties are conservative.

Comment: Also to complete: I feel that *Glücksprotokoll* carries a certain level of slight contempt or sneering, maybe because the word implies the parties are documenting their (self-assessed!) good luck for the sake of their own satisfaction with their work.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think the notion of a complacent smile comes across in the English version as well.